# Does Thread_UseAllCPUGroups only affect default Task Scheduler?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, threadpool

Documentation says the following regarding the Thread_UseAllCPUGroups runtime setting..."When a computer has multiple CPU groups, enabling this element causes the runtime to distribute managed threads across all CPU groups" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/thread-useallcpugroups-element)  This would seem to imply that, by default, a .NET process can only leverage a single CPU group on a multi-CPU group system without making a configuration change.

In practice though, does Thread_UseAllCPUGroups actually affect all thread dispatch techniques (such as new Thread()) or is it limited to changing behavior of the default .NET task scheduler?

In testing on multi-CPU group servers with less than 64 cores, I'm able to push total CPU utilization past what should be possible for the individual CPU group without enabling this setting.

Comment: "This would seem to imply that, by default, a .NET process can only leverage a single processor on a multi-processor system ". It implies no such thing. There's a difference between processors and processor groups. Try running your code on a server with more than 64 cores.

Comment: Good clarification.  I'll update the question accordingly. Unfortunately, I only have ready access to machines with multiple CPU groups but they do not have more than 64 cores.

Comment: Huh? Why would Windows configure multiple CPU groups if there are less than 64 cores? That seems very unlikely. The only reason to introduce cpu groups is due to an old API limit of representing used CPUs in a 64bit word.

Comment: @Voo Some servers are configured to report multiple CPU groups even if below the 64 cores limit. That's the case of HP Gen9 servers with old BIOS versions, for instance: https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c04650594

Comment: I had a quick look at the .net core source code, and saw two main impacts for the setting: 1/ if enabled, new threads are spread on the available cpu groups (if disabled, nothing is done, so this is left at the OS' discretion), 2/ To compute the number of logical cpus (`Environment.ProcessorCount`), if the setting is not enabled, the CLR will use the GetSystemInfo API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsysteminfo), which according to the documentation will only return the number of cpus on the current cpu group

Comment: In the end I'm very surprised by your result. Are you absolutely sure you have multiple cpu groups? Note that you can have multiple numa nodes in the same cpu group, which can be confusing